# android 4.0 cursor android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access

Tags: android, listview, contacts

Please check the contact list code
http://www.pocketmagic.net/2011/03/android-contacts-a-simple-contact-selector/#.UNe0j7YzAQQ

When I run the code on android 4.0+

It will appear the error android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access

2.3 version works normally.